# Listening for system events in python on Android?

Tags: android, python

I simply want to catch a system event when a Wifi connection is established (although other system events would be interesting too), not regularly poll myself. Is that even possible with python on Android?

Comment: What are you using to run python on android?

Comment: QPython. But it doesn't matter, I'll use anything that gives me that capability.